# How to create inline grid editing using kendo ui in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to create Inline grid editing in MVC using kendo ui. I can edit records only not edit or delete. and delete time generates error. Please anybody inform me.

Comment: Refer to [Kendo Demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html)

Comment: Please post code of your try!

Comment: I referred demo. But You know there are not available controller so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from kendo ui website.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you must choose what you want inline grid have so many options.You can use dropdown ,textbox,checkbox if you want.And best choose go teleric and look